# Akka Actor Context become with Message

Tags: akka

I have a question with regards to the context become in Akka. I have the following Actor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    def active(state: State): Receive = {
    case Dispatch(power) => // Dispatch to the specified power value
      context.become(
        checkRamp(
          Observable.intervalAtFixedRate(cfg.rampRateInSeconds),
          State.dispatch(state.copy(setPoint = power))
        )
      )
      self ! SomeMessage
  }

  def checkRamp(obs: Observable[Long], state: State): Receive = {
    case SomeMessage => // do something
  }
}
```

Would the above work? I mean after doing a context become, could I send a message to the new context? Is this new message preserved? Of course I can try it, but just wanted to know. If this does not work, what is the alternative? I want to switch context and send a message to the new context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely getting what you mean by "could I send a message to the new context", but basically, when you switch context in an actor, you change its behaviour when receiving a message, such that `checkRamp` becomes the method that gets invoked when it receives a message, rather than the original `receive`. 
If that doesn't answer your question, can you please elaborate more over what you mean by "sending a message to the new context"?

Comment: So what I meant was, after doing a context become, would the message that I send in the next line be available to the checkRamp method?

Comment: Yes, that's what context.become does.